# Приходит пустой файл, PHP

Tags: php, файлы, email, sendmail, отправка

Пытаюсь сделать отправку на почту письма, все приходит и файл сам приходит, но он почему то пустой и размером 0кб.

```
<?php
$toowner = 'an.semeryanova@yandex.ru';
$toclient = $_POST['email'];

if ( isset( $_POST['sendMail'] ) ) {
  $name  = substr( $_POST['name'], 0, 64 );
  $tel = substr( $_POST['tel'], 0, 64 );
  $email   = substr( $_POST['email'], 0, 64 );
 // $message = substr( $_POST['message'], 0, 250 );
  $pathabs = __DIR__ ;
  $filemy = 'blank.xls'; 

  if ( !empty( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) and $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0 ) {
    $filepath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  } else {
    $filepath = $pathabs;
    $filename = $filemy;
  }

  $body = "Имя:\r\n".$name."\r\n\r\n";
  $body .= "Контактный номер:\r\n".$tel."\r\n\r\n";
  $body .= "E-mail:\r\n".$email."\r\n\r\n";
  //$body .= "Описание заказа:\r\n".$message;

$filepath2 = '';
$filename2 = '';

  send_mail($toclient, $body, $email, $filepath, $filename);

  send_mail($toowner, $body, $email, $filepath2, $filename2);

}




// Вспомогательная функция для отправки почтового сообщения с вложением
function send_mail($toclient, $body, $email, $filepath, $filename)
{
  $subject = 'Оптовый прайс';
  $boundary = "--".md5(uniqid(time())); // генерируем разделитель
  $headers = "From: ".$email."\r\n";   
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"\r\n";
  $multipart = "--".$boundary."\r\n";
  $multipart .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
  $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n";

  $body = $body."\r\n\r\n";

  $multipart .= $body;

  $file = '';
  if ( !empty( $filepath ) ) {
    $fp = fopen($filepath, "r");
    if ( $fp ) {
      $content = fread($fp, filesize($filepath));
      fclose($fp);
      $file .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";
      $file .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n";
      $file .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
      $file .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
      $file .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content))."\r\n";
    }
  }
  $multipart .= $file."--".$boundary."--\r\n";
    mail($toclient, $subject, $multipart, $headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: так filepath  то без имени файла, а только путь содержит? fopen($filepath  . filename, "r"); наверное, ну и слеш возможно между ними нужен

Comment: а где поставить слеш именно? не совсем понял

Comment: Я просто не знаю есть ли в filepath в конце слеш, если нет то нужно добавить $filepath ."/" . $filename чтобы получить корректный путь к файлу

Comment: $fp = fopen($filepath . $filename, "r"); так файл вообще не приходит

Comment: $filepath ."/" . $filename  тоже не помогло

Comment: Ну тогда добавьте в вопрос, или сами посмотрите чтоу вас хранится в этих переменных и вопросы сами думаю отпадут

Comment: эм, по подробнее ) если можно

Comment: добавьте в самом начале функции send_mail() var_dump($filepath); и var_dump($filename); чтобы посмотреть что в них

Comment: спасибо помогло, все работает